# Appcelerator Hyperloop Android - How to use certain Sensor Manager functions which use a pass by reference structure

Tags: android, appcelerator, android-sensors, sensormanager, hyperloop

I'm stepping into Hyperloop for the first time, specifically for Android currently, and although it's going fairly well I've had one issue which I will explain below.

I've successfully been able to get a handle to the Sensor Manager and set up a Sensor listener event to get values from the sensor.

If anyone needs that code here it is below

```
var AndroidAppPkg = require('android.app.*');
var AndroidHardware = require('android.hardware.*');
var Context = require('android.content.Context');
var Sensor = AndroidHardware.Sensor;
var SensorEvent = AndroidHardware.SensorEvent;
var SensorEventListener = AndroidHardware.SensorEventListener;
var SensorManager = AndroidHardware.SensorManager;
var Activity = AndroidAppPkg.Activity;
var Matrix = require('android.opengl.Matrix');

var activity = new Activity(Titanium.App.Android.getTopActivity());
var appContext = activity.getApplicationContext();

var obj = appContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

var sensorManager = SensorManager.cast( obj );

var sensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR);

Ti.API.info('Set up sensor event');
var sensorEvent = new SensorEventListener({
    onSensorChanged:function(event){
        // sensor values retrieve here
    }
});
```

What I'm having trouble with is how to use the Android Sensor Manager functions that involve passing a parameter by reference. For example `SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(float[] inR, int X, int Y, float[] outR)` includes an out array (a rotation matrix).

I tried this approach

```
var outR = new Array(16).fill(0);
SensorManager.remapCoordinateSystem(inR, SensorManager.AXIS_X, SensorManager.AXIS_Z, outR);
Ti.API.info(outR.join());
```

The outR array stays the same as when it was initialised, in this case an array of 16 0's. I've tested a few of the similar functions and have gotten the same result. I've been able to work around this issue by recreating each of the SensorManager functions I need and editing the function so it returns the variable but I was wondering if there was any way around this or if it's just a limitation of hyperloop? It's a waste of my time to be remaking the same functions with only a minor difference so I am hoping I've just missed something.

Thanks!